# form values lost if captcha error in codeigniter php

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, flash, reloaddata

I have created a website in php, the website has a signup form and google captcha in it. If the captcha is correct the form will submit successfully. If the captcha is wrong the same page will reload:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Captcha Error.');
redirect(base_url('signup'), 'Location');
```

The problem is the page is reloading with empty values, the user entered inputs are gone, can anyone please tell me what am i missing in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be because you're redirecting the page, try loading the `view` instead. Also, don't forget to use `set_value` in the `input` fields

Comment: @sauhardnc i am new to codeigniter, can you please post it as answe

Comment: To do that, I'll have to see your code but before doing so check this similar question out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232820/codeigniter-how-to-preserve-form-values-if-error-on-submit
It should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your form value in session, and autofill the form based on data in session.

```
//set formdata to session
$data_session = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'email' => $email
);
$this->session->set_userdata('form_data', $data_session);
```

And set the data when you load the register page, and set the value to your view.

```
//load session data if exist
$data['name'] = null;
$data['email'] = null;
if ($this->session->userdata('form_data') != null)
{
    $data['name'] = $this->session->userdata('form_data')['name'];
    $data['email'] = $this->session->userdata('form_data')['email'];
}
$this->load->view('register_view',$data);
```

Dont forget to remove the session if signup is successful.

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('form_data');
```

Alternatively you can also use HTTP method and POST / GET the data to the new page (dont use HTTP GET if you want to send the password).